# 10 Integers and 1 input that is asked too soon in Python 3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, arraylist

I'm trying to create a program right now where the user insert 10 integers, and then gets the possibility to do the following:

program: "What would you like to do?: 1. Show me the biggest integer. 2. Show me the smallest integer. 3. Show me the average of all numbers combined with one decimal. 4. Show me all the entered integers. 5. Terminate this program."

```
nr=[]
for i in range(10):
    a=int(input("Please Enter an integer. "))
    nr.append(a)
    s = [max(nr), min(nr), nr, sum(nr)/len(nr)]
    z = int((input("What would you like to do? Please enter a number between 1 to 4. ")))
    if z == 1:
        print(s[0])
    elif z== 2:
        print(s[0])
    elif z == 3:
        print(s[0])
    elif z == 4:
        print(s[0])
    else:
        print("Please select a number between 1 to 4.")
```

This is how far I've come, and now I'm just stuck. When I get the "Please enter an Integer" I enter, let's say for example "1". Then I get the "Please enter a number between 1 to 4" directly after that. I would also like the "Please enter a number between 1 to 4" list several options but got: "TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 5". I also would like a fifth option to terminate the program. I tried "brake" but I guess it doesn't work like that?

Comment: Right now, everything is indented in such a way that makes it part of the loop.  Shift every line starting from and including the line beginning with `s =` all the way to the left.  That is the only way Python will know that those lines are not part of the loop.  There's other stuff you'll need to do after that but this will get you started.  Remember that indentation is syntactically significant in Python (somewhat unique to that language.)

Comment: First of all: Thank you for the fast reply. I've tried shifting everything, but that gives me the "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" on "if z == 1:"

Comment: You can replace all the if statements with just `print(s[z])`.  Also, it looks like in your `s` array, the 3rd element should be swapped with the 4th, at least based on what you said in the description.  No need for an option 5, the program will just end after this anyway.

Comment: Actually I was kind of wrong about that.  Let me fix things up and I'll post as an answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The reason I also want a "stop program" option, is because i want the user to be able to stop the program earlier, if they like.

Comment: No prob.  Just posted the answer below.  Then I just noticed your most recent comment.  By "stop the program earlier", do you mean stopping at any point, like even before finishing entering the 10 numbers?  If so let me know here and I'll change my answer to show how to do that.

Comment: I re-read your description.  Updated so that there is an option 5, which just does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I've re-formatted and added some bits to get this example working. Hopefully you can follow everything I've changed from the comments, but feel free to ask.

```
nr=[]
for i in range(10):
    a=int(input("Please Enter an integer. "))
    nr.append(a)

#only calculate params after all numbers are entered (outside for loop)
s = [max(nr), min(nr), nr, sum(nr)/len(nr)]

while 1: #loop forever until user chooses "terminate this program"

    #print options in a nicely formatted way
    #triple quoted string allows newlines within literal definition (multiline strings)
    print("""What would you like to do?:
        1. Show me the biggest integer.
        2. Show me the smallest integer.
        3. Show me the average of all numbers combined with one decimal.
        4. Show me all the entered integers.
        5. Terminate this program.""")

    #we don't specifically need an integer if we're just picking a choice from a list of options
    z = input("input: ") 
    if z == "1": #choices are now strings so be sure to quote them
        print(s[0]) #be sure to select proper element from our list 's'
    elif z == "2":
        print(s[1])
    elif z == "3":
        print(s[3])
    elif z == "4":
        print(s[2])
    elif z == "5": #now that we are in a separate loop, break will bring us out of it
        break
    else:
        print("Please select a number between 1 to 5.")
```

Comment: Oh yeah I get it now! That makes so much sense, thank you so much! This was a very good explanation. Thank you for taking the time to get all the comments in there and not just leave me the code!

Comment: @JoelGreek 1st rule of programming: "Thoroughly comment everything". 2nd rule of programming: "Thoroughly comment everything" :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working version.  I will explain each change to get you started on programming Python.

```
nr=[]
for i in range(10):
    a=int(input("Please Enter an integer. "))
    nr.append(a)

s = [max(nr), min(nr), sum(nr)/len(nr), nr]

z = 0
while not 1 <= z <= 5:    
    z = int((input("What would you like to do? (1) Max ; (2) Min; (3) Avg; (4) All; (5) None. ")))    
if z != 5:
    print(s[z-1])
```

Here are the changes I made:

- As I originally said in the comments, we shift everything from the `s =` line to the left, to get it out of the input loop.  Remember indentation is syntactically significant.
- We swap the 3rd and 4th elements in your `s` array to conform to the description you had (option 3 is the average, option 4 prints the array)
- We set up a `while` loop to keep asking for a legal option input (1 thru 5). Notice how in Python, you can do things like `1 <= z <= 5`. This more natural notation is not something you find in many languages. Notice also how we had to set `z = 0`.  We could have set `z = 6` or `z = 99` or whatever - basically, any value not between 1 and 5. Without that, `z` is initialized to the special Python value `None` - the null value that is nowhere in the set of integers, and will thus fail the `1 <= z <= 5` test.
- We modify the message printed to the user just make the options clear
- Last but not least, rather than having all the `if` statements, we take advantage of the fact that the option number is the same as the index in the array of calculations we did. Well, almost the same, except that arrays in Python start at index `0`.  So, we subtract one from the option number, and that indexes right to the place in the array holding the desired calculation. The only exception is option 5, which is meant to do nothing. So, we still have just one `if` statement, which tests for that option 5.

Comment: Thank you! That actually all makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
nr=[]
for i in range(10):
    a=int(input("Please Enter an integer. "))
    nr.append(a)

while True:
    s = [max(nr), min(nr), sum(nr)/len(nr), nr]
    z = int((input("What would you like to do? Please enter a number between 1 to 4.\n1> Max Value\n2> Min Value\n3> Average\n4> Show All\n5> Terminate\n")))
    if (z-1) in range(0,4):
        print(s[z-1])
    elif z == 5:
        break
    else:
        print("Please select a number between 1 to 4.")
```